# Different keystrokes to hide

Tags: shortcut

I noticed that sometimes ctrl-L selects all and sometimes A works instead.  What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>A</kbd> will select all geometry.

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will select all geometry that is connected to your current selection.

For example, from this state in edit mode:
[image: 1]

Pressing <kbd>A</kbd> will result in this:
[image: 2]

Pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will result in this:
[image: 3]

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode Ctrl+L selects all geometry that is **linked** to the geometry you have selected.
So if you have a mesh with two (or more) 'loose parts', and you select one face of one of those partes, hitting ctrl+L will select all the faces in that part, but not the other one(s). While A will select every face in the mesh regardless of being in another part.

That's why Ctrl+L doesn't do anything unless you already have something selected.

Answer (score -3):

<kbd>A</kbd> selects all geometry.
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> selects linked geometry. In edit mode, if you have geometry selected, it would let you select all of the geometry connected. Here is a quote from [docs.blender.org](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/linked.html):

> Select geometry connected to already selected elements. This is often useful when a mesh has disconnected, overlapping parts, where isolating it any other way would be tedious.

Comment: No, invert selection is ctrl+i.
ctrl+L is "select all linked".

Comment: @Alexandre Marcati I edited my response.